# Re-structure in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> EDIT: I'm doing a survey with Angular. In this project, the questions will be added dynamically and answer models will be given to the questions.
>   For example, "multiple selection, plain text, star rating"

Since the number of questions and the number of replies are dynamic, I also give "input name" dynamically. And the object created when I post the form is as follows.

I have such an object.

```
    {
    "title": "anket başlığı",
    "sms": "sms mesajı",

    "question-1": "bu birinci soru",
    "answer-1": "1",

    "question-2": "bu ikinci soru",
    "answer-2": "6",
    "answers-2-1": "cevap 1",
    "answers-2-2": "cevap 2",
    "answers-2-4": "cevap 4",

    "question-4": "soru 4",
    "answer-4": "7",
    "answers-4-5": "qwe1",
    "answers-4-6": "qwe2",
    "answers-4-7": "qwe3",

    "question-5": "soru 5",
    "answer-5": "6",
    "answers-5-10": "ccc3",
    "answers-5-11": "ccc4"
}
```

In this object "question-1" is 1st question and "answer-1" is the type of 1st question's answer. "question-2" is 2nd question and "answer-2" is the type of 2nd question's answer and "answers-2-1, answers-2-2, answers-2-4" are answer of the 2nd question.

I want to doing dynamicly shape of "question-1, question-2, question-4, question-5" in this object.

> EDIT:  I need to bring this object to the following structure in order to send web service.

```
    {
    "title": "anket başlığı",
    "sms": "sms mesajı",
    "questions" : [
        {
            "question": "bu birinci soru",
            "answer_model_id": "1",
            "answers": []
        },
        {
            "question": "bu ikinci soru",
            "answer_model_id": "6",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answers": "cevap 1"
                },
                {
                    "answers": "cevap 2"
                },
                {
                    "answers": "cevap 4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "soru 4",
            "answer_model_id": "7",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answers": "qwe1"
                },
                {
                    "answers": "qwe2"
                },
                {
                    "answers": "qwe3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "soru 5",
            "answer_model_id": "6",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answers": "ccc3"
                },
                {
                    "answers": "ccc4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> EDIT 2: I keep the number of questions with a variable. I know I need to do this by setting up a loop with this variable. But the "question-first, question-2, 4-question, question-5" i did not know how to distinguish.

Comment: Just saying _"I want"_ won't get you very far, unfortunately... What have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck? Tell us and we'll be glad to help. But you need to post some code for us to work with

Comment: Sorry. I could not write the question I wanted to ask in detail because English is not at an adequate level. But I have edited the question, and I talk about my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object as reference to the question with the same index. For assignment of a given key, you could split the keys and assign the values by the check of the key.

```js
var data = { "title": "anket başlığı", "sms": "sms mesajı", "question-1": "bu birinci soru", "answer-1": "1", "question-2": "bu ikinci soru", "answer-2": "6", "answers-2-1": "cevap 1", "answers-2-2": "cevap 2", "answers-2-4": "cevap 4", "question-4": "soru 4", "answer-4": "7", "answers-4-5": "qwe1", "answers-4-6": "qwe2", "answers-4-7": "qwe3", "question-5": "soru 5", "answer-5": "6", "answers-5-10": "ccc3", "answers-5-11": "ccc4" },
    reference = {};

data.questions = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
    var [key, index] = k.split('-');
    if (!index) {
        return;
    }
    if (!reference[index]) {
        data.questions.push(reference[index] = {});
    }
    if (key === 'question') {
        reference[index].question = data[k];
    }
    if (key === 'answer') {
        reference[index].answer_model_id = data[k];
    }
    if (key === 'answers') {
        reference[index].answers = reference[index].answers || [];
        reference[index].answers.push({ answers: data[k] });
    }
    delete data[k];
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked exactly the way I wanted.